# Why time dependent workflow is not applicable for record that get closes based on auto response and other workflow rule?

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow, case-auto-response

Hi I have created a Time base workflow to trigger email if Status is not equal to closed. this is getting applicable for all the records. However for record that get closed based on other field say for eg: If contact reason = Duplicate and when user saves the record the status will automatically changes to closed . for these kind the records the email is Still getting triggered for the Time based even if the case status is  closed similarly if the user uses the CloseCase custom button to close is also has the same issue.

Comment: This should not happen. Setting case status to closed, by any means, should remove the time trigger from the time based workflow queue. I would look closely at the rule and at any other rules and processes on the object. try deactivating all rules except this one, and go to monitor - time based workflow and watch what is happening as you create and update records. If all else fails try changing the rule criteria from evaluating case status to evaluating the isClosed field.

Comment: @gorav I tried this as well still I face the same problem. the reason I found is the Is closed checkbox will get checked only if the case is closed on the creation .In my case we have a another workflow to update close field automatically if Contact reason field==Duplicate case. Only these kind of cases still showing up in the monitoring queue even after the case is closed.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you need to note when create Time-Dependent Workflow is the Evaluation Criteria, make sure it is set to created or created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria only. Created, and every time it’s edited will NOT allow you to have Time-Dependent Actions.

Comment: Iam using created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria